# curl (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer with a simple docker run

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, curl, reset

Yesterday this image was working fine.

But from today i have always the same error.

Here the command :

```
sudo docker run --name matter -d --publish 8065:8065 --add-host dockerhost:127.0.0.1 mattermost/mattermost-preview
```

When i curl :

> curl: (56) Recv failure: Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant
>
> English : curl (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer with a
> simple docker run

Sometimes when i wait i can access to my localhost.

When i i do this :

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
```

I have this :

> tcp6       0      0 :::8065                 :::*
> LISTEN      25772/docker-proxy

I don't understand this error :/

I am on Linux Ubuntu 18

Comment: Please share more details. What does "When i curl" mean? And how is this related to programming?

Comment: In the shell i make this : curl 0.0.0.0:8065
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connexion ré-initialisée par le correspondant

Answer (score 1):

The server takes a while to get ready to accept requests.

If you do
`sudo docker logs matter`
you can see the output of the server. Wait until you see a message like this

> {"level":"info","ts":1624436113.1993275,"caller":"app/server.go:1226","msg":"Server
> is listening on [::]:8065","address":"[::]:8065"}

before you start making requests.

Comment: OK but its take time :/